# Value of textarea would not be updated with javascript getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form:

```
<label>Subtitle:</label><br>
  <input required type="text" id="articleSubtitle" size="50" value="<?php somePhp Code here?>" />

<label>Date:</label><br>
  <input required type="date" id="articleDate" size="48" value="<?php somePhp Code here?>" />

<label>Article:</label><br>
  <textarea required name="articleText" rows="10" cols="50" id="articleText" class="showEditor"><?php 
                    ignoreThis ?></textarea>
```

And the following script:

```
var subtitle = document.getElementById("articleSubtitle");
var articleDate = document.getElementById("articleDate");
var articleText = document.getElementById("articleText");

an onclick function{
 subtitle.value = "";
 articleDate.value = "16/16/2015"
 articleText.value = "";
}
```

The problem is the following:
the javascript code is able to change the value of the subtitle, but unable to change the date field or the textarea values.

If I change the input type from "date" to "text" it works. And even if I ignore this, I still can't change the textarea. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide more code.

Comment: here is the whole code. php elements will not work obviously. https://jsfiddle.net/d8b3qq1w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems:**

1. You are accessing component before its render so that variable are null.you can check using `debugger`

   ```
   var subtitle = document.getElementById("articleSubtitle");
   var articleDate = document.getElementById("articleDate");
   var articleText = document.getElementById("articleText");
   ```
2. Second one,As above pointed your date formate of article date variable.
   You variable should be YYYY-MM-DD.

   **A simple Javascript code**

   ```
    <html>
    <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">     </script>  


   <script>
   function changeval(){
   var subtitle = document.getElementById("articleSubtitle");
   var articleDate = document.getElementById("articleDate");
   var articleText = document.getElementById("articleText");
   subtitle.value = "123";
   articleDate.value = "2015/16/16";
   articleText.value = "xyz";
   }

   </script>

   </head>
   <body>   
   <label>Subtitle:</label><br>
     <input required type="text" id="articleSubtitle" size="50" value="xyz" />

   <label>Date:</label><br>
     <input required type="date" id="articleDate" size="48" value="16/16/2015" />

   <label>Article:</label><br>
     <textarea required name="articleText" rows="10" cols="50" id="articleText" class="showEditor">vasim vanzara</textarea>
   <button value="Changevalue" onclick="changeval()"/>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: The date is working now, thanks! :D

Comment: The textarea is not so easy on me. you said that I'm accessing component s before its render. Ok. but how come everything else can be changed but not this? I tried your code as well, nothing. :/

Comment: Ok. Something I didn't mention earlier is, that the tinyMCE wyswyg editor is applied to the textarea. I removed it, now it works. I think I should go over to their site first, to find out what the heck! Thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

Value of date should be in format `YYYY-MM-DD` instead of `MM/DD/YYYY` that would fix first problem.

See: [HTML Markup Language#input.date.attrs.value](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value) for reference.

I cannot reproduce second problem, you can see my code sample it's the same as you provided.

```js
var subtitle = document.getElementById("articleSubtitle");
var articleDate = document.getElementById("articleDate");
var articleText = document.getElementById("articleText");


 subtitle.value = "";
 articleDate.value = '2016-02-12';
 articleText.value = "111111";
```

```html
<label>Subtitle:</label><br>
  <input required type="text" id="articleSubtitle" size="50" value="<?php somePhp Code here?>" />

<label>Date:</label><br>
  <input required type="date" id="articleDate" size="48" value="" />

<label>Article:</label><br>
  <textarea required name="articleText" rows="10" cols="50" id="articleText" class="showEditor">123</textarea>
```

Comment: ,"same id and name of textarea." its doesn't matter.

Comment: I have change the name of the textarea, still not working.

Comment: The format of the date still not affect it. Sorry. it does, that one is working now.

Comment: Please try,above code.

Comment: @VasimVanzara thanks for pointing to it. I've checked you are right. Just thought that fact that name and id are living in same namespace could couse some problems ...

Comment: okay,Thanks for advice.I will remember.